# Can't find uploaded files after PHP image upload

Tags: php, upload

I'm uploading files from an iPhone app to PHP using the following code:

```
<?php
    if ($_FILES["media"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["media"]["error"] . "<br />";
    } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["media"]["name"];
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["media"]["type"];
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["media"]["size"] / 1024);
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["media"]["tmp_name"];

    if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["media"]["name"])) {
        echo $_FILES["media"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["media"]["tmp_name"],
        "uploads/" . $_FILES["media"]["name"]);
        echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["media"]["name"];
    }
}
?>
```

Afterwards, I get the success message saying "uploads/2542543.jpg" - but I can't seem to find where the image is actually stored.  Is the filepath relative to the php file (which is in php - and has an uploads folder) or is it absolute from the root??

**EDIT**:  Looks like the file should have ended up in php/uploads/filename.jpg - but it doesn't appear to be making it.  I don't quite understand why - anyone have any idea?

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 why would that have a bearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an absolute path from the root

```
/uploads/2543.jpg
```

This is a relative path from your PHP document

```
uploads/2543.jpg
```

So you're working with a relative path (note the missing `/` at the start)

Comment: You can give the `move_uploaded_file` function a fixed file path. That should solve it

Comment: Would that be placed at the /var/www/html root (where my index.php is)???  I just tried that the file is just not showing up at all...

Comment: my webroot is at `/home/johnp/site.com/` so the function would look like `move_uploaded_file(... ,"/home/johnp/site.com/uploads/" . $_FILES["media"]["name"]);` Make sure it's writable. Currently, you're trying to upload into the `/uploads/` folder in the same level as your PHP file. Check whether the folder exists and has write permissions for the user that apache is running as

Answer (score 2):

This is defined in php.ini using the `upload_tmp_dir` directive. If that's not set, it uses the system default, which you can figure out using [`sys_get_temp_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php). I believe it defaults to `/tmp` on Linux, and `C:\Windows\Temp\` on Windows.

Comment: This is correct if OP wants to look at where it initially goes. Right now he's actually having issues with where his files go when moving them

Comment: Correct John, I can't find the file... it's like it's not actually being uploaded.